# Ubuntu MATE 15.10 menu bars not displaying correctly

Tags: themes, 15.10, mate, ubuntu-mate

[image]

As you can see in the above image, VLC's menu bar doesn't use the same Numix theme as the rest of my OS. Instead, it uses something that looks out of the 90's. It happens regardless of the theme used, and only happens in MATE. Works fine in Unity and GNOME. Any way to fix this?

Other apps affected: Focuswriter, which also seems to refuse to use the Numix icons...and that seems to be it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for VLC.

Navigate to Tools>Preferences.

Under interface, click the dropdown menu for force window style. Select "GTK+."

Fixes it all. Not just the menu items, but also right-click menus, interface, etc.